# Bott and Tu, Thom Class pg 64

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

> [Prop 6.18,pg 64](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf):The Thom class $\Phi$ on a rank $N$ oriented vector bundle $E$ can be uniquely characterized as the cohomology class in $H^n_{cv}(E)$ which restricts to the generator of $H^n_c(F)$ on each fiber $F$.

The proof wrote that

> If $\Phi'$ is a coho. class in $H^n_{cv}(E)$ that restricts to a generator on each fiber then for $w \in H^n(M)$, 
>   $$ w \wedge \pi_* \Phi' = w. $$

**I do not see how this holds from the definition of $\pi_*$**

Definitions:

> From Thom Isomorphism for an oriented bundle $E$ over $M$, we have isomorphism between de Rham coho. and compact vertical coho. 
>   $$ H^*(M) \rightarrow H^{*-n}_{cv}(E)$$
>   We define $\Phi$ the **Thom class** to be the image of $1$ in $H^0(M)$ under the above Thom isomorphism.

---

> A form $w \in \Omega^*_{cv}(E)$ is locally of type (I) or (II), the map 
>       \begin{align*}
>  (I)  \quad & \pi^* \phi f(x, t_1, \ldots, t_n) dt_{i_1} \ldots d_{t_r} \mapsto 0 , \quad r< n \\ 
>  (II) \quad & \pi^* \phi f(x,t_1, \ldots, t_n) dt_1 \ldots dt_n \mapsto \phi \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x,t_1, \ldots, t_n) dt_1 \ldots dt_n 
>  \end{align*}
>       is our $\pi_* :\Omega^{*}_{cv}(E) \rightarrow \Omega^{*-n}(M)$. $E$ a vector bundle over $M$.

Comment: Can you include some more details in your question? I'm not sure which definition for a Thom class you wish to use (as it stands the stated theorem is a perfectly suitable definition). And what is $\Phi'$? And what is $\omega$?

Comment: I have added the details, but more can be found in the text. Tell me if things are still unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite agree with the exact wording of the statement in the book, since you could always multiply such a $\Phi'$ by a non-zero real number to get another class which restricts to a generator in each fibre. I suggest working locally and studying the equation $\pi_*(\pi^*\omega\wedge \Phi')$ which appears in the book, using the description of the map $\pi_*$ to see the result.